# Export from SAS to Excel in month name sheets

Tags: sas

Can you, please, help me to find a solution for my export from SAS to Excel.

Here it's my export procedure:

```
%let today=%sysfunc(today());  
%let date1= %sysfunc(intnx(month,&today,-1,B));  
%let expectdate1=%sysfunc(putn(%eval(&date1),monname8.));  
proc export  
data=WORK.table  
DBMS=XLSX  
outfile="C:\FILE.xlsx"  
REPLACE;  
SHEET="&expectdate1";  
run;**
```

The export creates me, as expected, a worksheet named "August" into FILE.xlsx. 
  My problem is when I'm inserting another workheet before the just created one (August). If I manually create a July worksheet before August, then my export procedure doesn't replace data from August, but it's gonna add the new information into July worksheet.

Thank you in advance for your solution.

Regards,
Dan

Comment: I don't think I understand the issue.  I ran this; then I made date1 subtract an extra month (to get July); I got a workbook with 2 sheets, July and August, with data in each.  What do you want that's different than that?

Comment: -also, `MONNAME8.` is not long enough for all months (c.f. `SEP-TEM-BER`).

Comment: What version of SAS are you using? DBMS=XLSX didn't support multi sheet workbooks initially.

Comment: What is the question? Are you concerned that the new JULY sheet is not the first in the workbook? Or Is the old JULY sheet that you added outside of SAS not being deleted?  Or is in fact the old AUGUST sheet being replaced by the data that should be in the new JULY sheet?  What happens if you don't mess with the file outside of SAS?

Comment: Thank you all for the answers. I'm using 6.1 version.

Comment: 6.1 is a version of Enterprise Guide, not of SAS.  But it's likely old enough that XLSX won't support multiple sheets, as Reeza supposed.

Comment: When I ran for the first time the procedure, the FILE.xlsx is created with data in August worksheet . I manually added an worksheet named July in FILE.xlsx, located before August worksheet. I cleared the August worksheet. Now I have the FILE.xlsx with two empty worksheets: July and August. When I run again the procedure, all data is going into July and not in August, as I expected.

Comment: Sorry. SAS version is 9.4

Comment: @Tom: If I don't mess with the file outside SAS, then a new worksheet will be added ad the beginning of each month with data from the previous month. I'm expecting after one year, to have the new data replacing the actual data from each worksheet and I don't know if it's gonna happen in this way.

Comment: @DanL That's not at all what you asked in your question!  Yes, it will happen that way, if you name the sheet "July" it will replace next year with whatever data is July 2018.

Comment: @Joe: I'm sorry for not being clear in my first request. I'm concern by actual behaviour what seams to add information into the first worksheet of the file instead of intended worksheet.

Comment: You're saying you run an export that puts data in August, but actually is putting information into the July sheet?  That's definitely not what happens when I run this, although I have 9.4 TS1M4 while you probably have base 9.4 given your EG version, so maybe there could've been bugs in earlier versions?

Comment: I think the probleme is solved. I've changed DBMS=XLSX with DBMS=EXCEL and I've got what I was expecting: information is added in worksheet named by expectdate1 variable, no metter what is the worksheet position. Thank you all again for your useful comments.

Answer (score 0):

The probleme is solved. I've changed DBMS=XLSX with DBMS=EXCEL and I've got what I was expecting: information is added in worksheet named by expectdate1 variable, no metter what is the worksheet position.